How can we know which pools is a token at?
I need to know if a token is at raydium, meteora, pumpFun etc ...
I know we have the updateAuthority that tell us where was the token created, but when a token is created at pumpFun and moved to raydium after it reaches the required mcap, then updateAuth will keep telling me its pumpFun even tho its on raydium already...
Maybe the programId ? But I could not find a pattern on this guy and also there are thousands of programIds per txn
